# echo to gid_map fails but uid_map success

Tags: linux-mint, namespace, unshare

I'm trying to map the user and group ids in new namespace by writing to uid_map and gid_map files.

So on **terminal-1** I'm doing

```
vaibhav@vaibhav:~$ unshare -U /bin/sh
$ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
$ echo $$
2506
```

then I open new terminal i.e. **terminal-2** and I do

```
vaibhav@vaibhav:~$ echo '0 1000 1' > /proc/2506/
uid_map
vaibhav@vaibhav:~$ echo '0 1000 1' > /proc/2506/
gid_map
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

now if I check on **terminal-1**

```
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

I know we can write to uid_map & gid_map file only once but it is failing on first write itself.

I want to know why writing to gid_map failing. I'm using `Linux Mint 20.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific limitation added to unprivileged users since Linux 3.19 when attempting to map the user's group(s): they have to forfeit their right to alter supplementary groups. This is usually to prevent an user to *remove* itself from a group which acts as a deny filter for files with ownership like `someuser:denygroup` and mode `u=rw,g=,o=r`.

Without this restriction an user could just call [`setgroups(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/setgroups.2) and empty its supplementary groups list.

This is documented in [`user_namespaces(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7):

> **Writing "deny" to the `/proc/[pid]/setgroups`** file before writing to
> `/proc/[pid]/gid_map` will permanently disable `setgroups(2)` in a user
> namespace and **allow writing to `/proc/[pid]/gid_map` without having the
> CAP_SETGID capability in the parent user namespace**.

So for OP's case:

```
echo deny > /proc/2506/setgroups
```

will forfeit the control over supplementary groups and allow to complete with:

```
echo '0 1000 1' > /proc/2506/gid_map
```

Notes:

- An user can only map its own uid/gid to an other one and the only interesting values are itself or *root*. To have more possibilities, one can use the setuid-root helpers [`newuidmap`](https://manpages.debian.org/uidmap/newuidmap.1) and [`newgidmap`](https://manpages.debian.org/uidmap/newgidmap.1) to use the per-user allocated ranges in [`/etc/subuid`](https://manpages.debian.org/passwd/subuid.5) and [`/etc/subgid`](https://manpages.debian.org/passwd/subgid.5). That's a part of how user unprivileged containers are able to actually work: with privileged helpers.
- As a security remark, as the privileged command `newgidmap` writes `allow` to `/proc/[pid]/setgroups` before proceeding, just having this command available around allows to escape the *denygroup* "jail" anyway. This command is ubiquitous in environments where users can run their own unprivileged containers.